# Create multiple 2-column bar plots plotting a particular factor against all factors in a loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame that contains 4 columns. The first, second, third, and fourth columns details the different locations (factors), number of successes, number of attempts, and percentage of success (second column / third column * 100), respectively.

The data would look something like the following:

```
location <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
success <- c(12, 40, 30, 10, 20)
attempts <- c(20, 54, 32, 12, 26)
perc_success <- c(60, 74, 94, 83, 76)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(location, success, attempts, perc_success))
```

I want to loop the creation of multiple 2-column bar plots that plots a particular locations percentage of success against the average percentage of success across all locations.

Meaning, I want a bar plot that has 2 columns, with the x-axis comprising of location "A" and location "all locations", with the y-axis showing percentage of success for location "A" and location "all locations."

I want to loop the same process above and create another bar plot plotting location B against all locations, location C against all locations, etc.

What I am doing now is to manually compute an "all locations" row to the excel data before importing it into R and then manually plotting each location against all location.

Please see the link below for the desired output that I am looking for (in this case, Location A against all locations).

Thanks in advance!

[Barplot Example: Location A against all Locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sf5mp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)

location <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
success <- c(12, 40, 30, 10, 20)
attempts <- c(20, 54, 32, 12, 26)
perc_success <- c(60, 74, 94, 83, 76)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(location, success, attempts, perc_success))

#Calculate average value
avg <- mean(perc_success)

#Create list to store plots in
plotvec<-vector("list",length=5)

for(i in c(1:5)){
  #Create a burner data frame with only the relevant data
  burner <- data.frame(c(paste(location[i]),"avg"),c(perc_success[i],avg))
  names(burner) <- c("location","perc_success")

  #Create a plot from that buner data frame
  plot <- ggplot(data=burner,aes(y=perc_success,x=location)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity")

  #Store plot in list
  plotvec[[i]]<-plot
}

#Display all plots
plotvec
```

Does this help? Feel free to reply with any questions.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Just curious, I've got two questions. First, what does the "avg" in c(paste(location[i]), "avg") mean? Why is there an "avg" and a avg? Second, is it possible to use the apply function to do the same thing? Thanks again!

Comment: @DTYK Great questions! The "avg" is there so that when you create the plot, it labels the column correctly. avg with no quotes calls the variable that stores the number. I'm sure you could use an apply statement, but I'm not great with those, so I couldn't tell you how.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Much appreciated. Cheers!